# How to Filter markers on Mapbox based on geojson information?

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox

So, I want to try to create a nav/filter based on mapbox, which will filter pubs based on their type, either Independent or a Pub Chain. I added the pub type in the geojson, but how do I create a filter based on the information in the geojson?

I tried creating a filter based on this link https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/ but it's more based on icons...

````
let filters = document.getElementById("filters");

let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/jlsr10/ck029molz05p11cock35wlyy9',
  center: [-0.133677, 51.526631],
  zoom: 12
});

let geojson = {
    "id": "places",
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "The World's End",
          "PubType": "Independent",
          "times": "Monday-Thursday: 11.00-0.00" + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 11.00-1.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 12.00-23.00"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.14222681522369385,
            51.53918203198429
          ]
        }
      },
       {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "The Black Heart",
          "PubType": "Independent",
          "times": "Monday-Tuesday: 15.00-23.00" + "<br>" + "Wednesday-Thursday: 15.00-1.00"  + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 12.00-2.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 12.00-23.00"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.141786,
            51.539003
          ]
        }
      }
      ,{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "The Devonshire Arms",
          "PubType": "Independent",
          "times": "Monday-Wednesday: 14.00-0.00" + "<br>" + "Thursday: 14.00-1.00"  + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 14.00-2.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 14.00-0.00"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.14223217964172363,
            51.54096705495758
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "The Unicorn",
          "PubType": "Independent",
          "times": "Monday-Thursday: 12.00-23.00" + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 12.00-0.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 12.00-23.00"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.12938976287841797,
            51.54885034693916
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "Garlic and Shots",
          "PubType": "Independent",
          "times": "Monday-Thursday: 17.00-0.00" + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 16.00-1.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 17.00-23.30"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.13152748346328735,
            51.51379710359405
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "Crobar",
          "PubType": "Independent",
          "times": "Monday-Saturday: 16.00-3.00" + "<br>" + "Sunday: Closed"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.1302802562713623,
            51.51482699380818
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "Slim Jim's Liquor Store",
          "PubType": "Independent",
          "times": "Monday-Wednesday: 17.00-2.00" + "<br>" + "Thursday: 14.00-1.00"  + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 14.00-2.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 14.00-0.00"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.10267496109008789,
            51.53812099449894
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "Aces and Eights Saloon Bar",
          "PubType": "Independent",
          "times": "Monday-Thursday: 16.00-1.00" + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 16.00-2.30"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 16.00-1.00"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.1383929,
            51.556696
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "Ace Cafe",
          "PubType": "Independent",
          "times": "Monday-Thursday: 7.00-22.30" + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 7.00-11.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 7.00-10.30"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.277751, 51.541419 
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "Brewdog",
          "PubType": "Pub Chain",
          "times": "Monday-Thursday: 12.00-23.30" + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 12.00-0.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 12.00-10.30"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.140905, 51.538394
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "The Draft House",
          "PubType": "Pub Chain",
          "times": "Monday-Wednesday: 12.00-23.00" + "<br>" + "Thursday: 12.00-0.00" + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 12.00-1.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: 12.00-10.30"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.138385, 51.541540
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "name": "The Draft House",
          "PubType": "Pub Chain",
          "times": "Monday-Thursday: 12.00-23.00" + "<br>" + "Friday-Saturday: 12.00-0.00"  + "<br>" + "Sunday: Closed"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.135732, 51.519278
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  };


// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
// create a DOM element for the marker
    let el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';

// add marker to map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
  .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 25})
  .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.name + '</h3>' + '<h4>Opening Times</h4>' +'<p>'+ marker.properties.times +'</p>'))
  .addTo(map);
});```



I would like the filter to filter Independent pubs, and pub chain pubs for the user.
````

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding markers, then removing and re-adding markers on filter change, consider adding a layer and updating it's source.

Add a geojson layer:

```js
map.addLayer({
  id: "places",
  type: "symbol",
  source: {
    type: "geojson",
    data: geojson
  },
  layout: {
    "icon-image": "bar-15",
    "icon-size": 1.25,
    "icon-allow-overlap": true,
  }
});
```

And then filter and update source:

```js
const filterElem = document.getElementById('pubTypeFilter');

filterElem.onchange = () => {
  const pubType = filterElem.value;
  if (pubType) {
    const newGeoJSON = {...geojson };
    newGeoJSON.features = geojson.features.filter(feature => feature.properties.PubType === pubType);
    map.getSource('places').setData(newGeoJSON);
  }
};
```

Here's a codepen that does that: https://codepen.io/manishraj/full/BaBrJwr

Answer (score 1):

You can use map.setFilter

map.setFilter('places', ['==', 'PubType', 'Independent']);

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setfilter